# Show $\log(1+x)$ is not a contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms

Show $F:[0,\infty] \to [0,\infty]$, $F(x) = \log(1+x)$ is not a contraction mapping.

Attempt:

Assume $F$ is a contraction mapping, then we have that $\forall x,y \in [0,\infty)$, $|F(x) - F(y) | \leq \lambda |x-y| $ for $\lambda \in (0,1)$. In particular let $y = 0$ then we have $|F(x)| = \lambda |x|$ so $\left | \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x} \right | \leq \lambda$, and taking the limit of both sides as $x \to 0$ we get $1 \leq \lambda$. I don't see anything wrong with this argument but I'm sure something is as there is a hint ot use the mean value theorem.

With the mean value theorem I get that $|F(x)| = \dfrac{|x|}{1+\theta}$ for some $\theta$ between $0$ and $x$, I don't see how I can use this to get a contradiction.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $F$ to be a contraction mapping, there must be a $C\in (0,1)$ such that $|F(x) - F(y)| \le C|x - y|$ for all $x,y\ge 0$. However, since $\lim_{x\to 0} \log(1 + x)/x = 1$, for every $C \in (0,1)$, there exists $x$ such that $1 - \log(1 + x)/x < 1 - C$, or $\log(1 + x) > Cx$, i.e., $|F(x) - F(0)| > C|x - 0|$. Therefore, $F$ is not a contraction mapping.

If you're set on using the mean value theorem, then suppose $F$ is a contraction with contraction constant $\lambda$, and let  $0 < x < (1 - \lambda)/\lambda$. By the mean value theorem, for some $c\in (0,x)$,

$$\frac{1}{1 + c} = \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} \le \lambda.$$

Thus

$$1 -\lambda \le \lambda(1 + c) - \lambda = \lambda c < \lambda x.$$

This implies

$$x > \frac{1 - \lambda}{\lambda},$$

a contradiction.

Comment: I don't follow - does this use the mean value theorem at all because that's specifically what I'm trying to use

Comment: @supersainx no it didn't -- the main point of the argument (which you were using as well) is that $\lim_{x\to 0} \log(1 + x)/x = 1$, which will give the desired contradiction.

Comment: Where does my argument fail?

Comment: @supersainx I don't see an issue with your argument. I just gave a direct proof that $F$ is not a contraction. The main point is the one I mentioned with the limit. It can be proved by application of the mean value theorem, but I think it's fair game to use the derivative of $\log(1 + x)$ at $x = 0$, L'hospital's rule, or Taylor expansion to get the result.

Comment: I don't have a problem using the limit as we've proved that a long time ago, I'm just trying to figure out how to prove that $F$ is not a contraction mapping directly using the mean value theorem.

Comment: I think I see my problem with my method - I divided by x when x can be 0 - is there a way to fix this? Perhaps this leads to the MVT?

Comment: @supersainx Ok, I've made an edit that uses the MVT, no limits involved (in the second paragraph).

Comment: Thank you! One last question - does my answer fail because $x$ could be $0$? and I divide by x? If not, why not?

Comment: @supersainx you just needed to say $|\log(1 + x)/x| \le \lambda$ for all $x \color{red}{>} 0$. Other than that, your solution is correct.

Comment: Yes but what do we say about the $x = 0$ case? We don't get a contradiction

Comment: @supersainx you're misunderstanding. From that step I mentioned, you say that taking the limit as $x\to 0^+$ results in $1 \le \lambda$, contradicting the assumption that $\lambda < 1$.

Comment: Oh, I see - so since we assumed it holds $\forall x \in [0,\infty)$ we don't care about one specific $x$ i.e. $x = 0$? Is this what you mean

Comment: @supersainx if it holds for all $x \in [0,\infty)$, in particular it holds for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: Yes I agree. I just didn't like how we left out the $x = 0$ case

Comment: Thanks for your help! You're very kind.